# How can we evaluate a string in the format "AND(value1, OR(value2,value3), value4)" using javascript?

Tags: javascript, salesforce

Suppose I have data with field values coming from server side response as

```
data: {
value1: '12',
value2: ''.
value3: 'some string',
value4: '34'
}
```

and I have another api response with the formula string that is to be evaluated from frontend Javascript:

```
{
formula: "AND(value1, OR(value2,value3), value4)"
}
```

How can I evaluate this formula from JS, provided formula can be dynamic like:

```
{
formula: "AND(value1, value2, value3, value4)"
}
```

Comment: You've to create a parser to interpret the formulas to JS. Doesn't the API documentation contain any help for how to use the results? If it's a common known API, naming it would also help to answer the question.

Comment: @Teemu This is a Salesforce REST Api response for a request I am making to the salesforce record

Comment: I've tagged your question with salesforce, now it can be found by the Salesforce experts.

Comment: You are trying to recreate the Salesforce formula parser. I can't imagine it will always exactly match the expected result from Salesforce. Can you explain why you want to calculate a salesforce formula on the fly (as opposed to making the field in Salesforce and querying that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Let's have a function that can take multiple parameter and return `&&` operation.

```
function and(...args) { return args.reduce((acc, x) => { return acc && x }, true) }
```

Setting default as true.

2. we will do same for `||` operation

```
function or(...args) { return args.reduce((acc, x) => { return acc || x}, true) }
```

Setting default as true.

3. let's replace `AND` uppercase and `OR` uppercase to lowercase.

```
"AND(value1, OR(value2,value3), value4)".replace("AND", "and")
"OR(value1, OR(value2,value3), value4)".replace("OR", "or")
```

Let's use function `replace_and` and `replace_or` for this purpose

```
function replace_and(str) { return str.replace("AND", "and") }
function replace_or(str) { return str.replace("OR", "or")
```

4. Let's replace values in formula with actual values from data

Let's add this as a function and make it more smart by calculating as bool value here only while assigning it as a value. This can help us solve problem of having mixture of integers, strings and different types.

```
function replace_values(data, formula) {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((formula, [x, y]) => { 
                         bool = y ? true : false;
                         return formula.replace(x,bool); 
   }, formula)
}
```

5. Let's eval after running through all 4 steps.

```
eval("or(false, or(true))")
=> true
```

and we can evaluate as a chain of functions like this

```
formula = "AND(value1, OR(value2,value3))"
data = {
value1: '12',
value2: '',
value3: 'some string',
value4: '34'
}

replace_values(data, replace_and(replace_or(formula)))
=> "and(true, or(false,true))"

eval(replace_values(data, replace_and(replace_or(formula))))
=> true
```